# What does "said" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

Fred and George fight each other after Goblet of fire
punish them with beards:

> Fred: You **said**!
>
> George: You **said**!

What does "said" refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My interpretation is "You said [the spell would work]" to conceal their true ages from the goblet, which they both agree is the other's fault.

Answer (score 4):

You said we should do it. It was your idea.